# Error: could not find function "guides"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to run the following code in R, taken from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/):

```
library(ggplot2)
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
bp
# Remove legend for a particular aesthetic (fill)
bp + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately,  in the last command the system says:

```
Error: could not find function "guides"
```

I did a small search and find out that the guide function is included in the "scales" package, installed it and then called with:

```
library(scales)
```

the library seems to be loading but still get the same error. Any clues? I am using debian with a fresh installation.

I tried

```
bp + scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)
```

but get the following error

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (guide = FALSE)
```

The details of the R version are

```
>  R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "2"

$minor
[1] "15.1"

$year
[1] "2012"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "22"

$`svn rev`
[1] "59600"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)"

$nickname
[1] "Roasted Marshmallows"
```

and my version of Debian

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
Release:    7.4
Codename:   wheezy
```

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you using?  This code works for me.

Comment: idem. Plus why don't you use any of the two other options given?

Comment: This code works for me as well, try running this code in a clean environment, loading only ggplot2. This error might be due to naming conflict with either your code or the other libraries.

Comment: Works for me too, but you could try `bp + scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)` for the same effect.

Comment: you're using an old version or R, and presumably also old version of the relevant packages. You should upgrade (probably requires some linux/Debian-specific steps to update the list used by your package manager).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by updating the R version. Debian Wheezy stable version ships with a version of R which is rather old. In order to update R,  I followed this guidelines

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

after which one has to update the old R modules

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

then the example written above works perfectly!